# Starting an Window Manager on hybrid graphics system fails

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, window-manager, hybrid-graphics

I'm using Arch Linux. I installed the system nearly like described by the German beginners guide. 
The most important things according this problem:

Bootmanager: GRUB

Installed `nvidia`, otherwise booting fails, because my GPU is incompatible with nouveau

Installed:

```
xf86-intel-video
intel-ucode
xorg-server xorg-xinit xorg-utils xorg-server-utils
gnome gnome-extra
```

Added GNOME to systemd with `systemctl enable gdm`

When booting everything is OK, until the boot process reaches the target  "Graphical user interface", then the screen gets black and after a few seconds the GNOME error screen appears saying:

> Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again.

When clicking on the Log out button, displayed under this massage, the screen gets dark again and the error screen reappears after a few seconds.
The system is still available through the tty consoles.

I also tried to enable GNOME with the

> ~/.xinitrc

and

> startx

but the same error occurred.

I also tried to install Lxde for figuring out what the failure could be. In this case the boot process stops at the target "Graphical user interface".

I tried to use TWM but when starting it with `startx` the screen goes black.

Here is the output of `lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
```

It's a hybrid system of an Intel and a nvidia GPU. The status LED on my notebook shows that the nvidia GPU is in use. In Arch Linux forums the idea was that the problem is the hybrid graphics setup.

I tried to configure Bumblebee, but after installing and starting the deamon with `systemctl start bumblebeed`

It still uses the nvidia GPU; and running `optitun glxgears` shows the error:

```
[604.582697] [ERROR] Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) systemd-logind: failed to get session: PID 731 does not belong to any known session
```